# Bypass conversion of entire dist to matrix (Filter dist object)

Tags: r, matrix, euclidean-distance

I have a very big data frame that looks like this:

```
> head(df)
                  X       Y         Z
0:600000000 193.722 175.733 0.0998975
0:600000001 192.895 176.727 0.0998975
0:600000002 193.828 177.462 0.0998975
8:600000003 178.173 178.220 0.0998975
7:600000004 187.065 178.285 0.0998975
0:600000005 190.754 178.186 0.0998975

> dim(df)
[1] 65865     3
```

I want to calculate the euclidian distance in R and save the data into a matrix only if the distance is lower than a value (let's say 2). Normally I am doing this in multiple steps, and it will work fine if I have a small dataframe. The problem is my dataframe is too big, so the distance matrix is then 17Gb and I cannot even melt the entire thing.
This is what I am able to do when the dataframe is smaller

```
dist <- dist(df, method = "euclidean", diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE)
df_m <- melt(as.matrix(dist), varnames = c("ID", "neig"))
head(df_m)
       ID neig      value
1     1:1  1:1  0.0000000
2     1:2  1:1  3.4641016
3     1:3  1:1  6.9282032
4     1:4  1:1  3.4641016
5     1:5  1:1  3.2908965
6     1:6  1:1  3.1176915
7     2:7  1:1  0.1732051
8     2:8  1:1 10.3923048

#Filter to keep only distances smaller than 2
df_m_2 <- df_m %>% subset(value < 2)

> head(df_m_2)
      ID neig     value
1    1:1  1:1 0.0000000
7    2:7  1:1 0.1732051
62   1:2  1:2 0.0000000
73  3:13  1:2 0.1732051
123  1:3  1:3 0.0000000
139 4:19  1:3 0.1732051
```

Is there a way to get there (df_m_2) directly without having to convert to matrix and melt the entire dist since I can't do that because of how big it is?
Thanks